# How to get the path of the request in symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, request

I know of the method `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getPathInfo()` however in the docs it states that, that only returns the path of the request which is "relative" to the "executed script".How can I get the full path?and on a second note what does 'executed script' mean when all requests are going through the front controller?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`$request->getUri()` returns the absolute URL => `http://example.com/app.php/path`

`$request->getRequestUri()` returns the absolute path => `/app.php/path`

`$request->getPathInfo()` returns the path corresponding to your controller's action => `/path`

`getPathInfo` just subtracts the executed script (/app.php) from the request URI, so it returns the path relative to the executed script.

Comment: GetRequestUrl() seems to return the path and the query parameters.