# Best way to get a prod URI from symfony request - while being in dev environment

Tags: symfony, request, uri

I am storing url slugs in my database, like this: **/blog/important-article**. My BlogController then resolves any requests to a resource below **/blog** to the corresponding database entry.

This works fine, but in the dev environment I still have to use a workaround as the dev path is **/app_dev.php**/blog/important-article - which does not exist in the database:

```
public function blogAction(Request $request)
{
    $slug = $request->getRequestUri(); // matches to regex \/(app_dev.php\/)?blog\/.+
    //...
}
```

I tried two workarounds that both work, but I don't think they are the way to go:

1. Use `$slug = str_replace ('app_dev.php/', '', $slug);` in the controller.
2. Catch the actual slug (/blog/**important-article**) in the routing configuration and hand it over to the controller as an argument. Then do `$slug = '/blog/'.$slugPart;`

Is there a symfony way of getting the prod Uri (even while in dev environment)?

**[Edit:]** the ["possible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601869/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-request-in-symfony2) duplicate suggested by @gp_sflover has a completely different focus. It is more about the documentation/usage of `getPathInfo()` than about why and when to use it. My question on the other hand is about a specific use case - where `getPathInfo()` is the actual solution one might be looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the path of the request in symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601869/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-request-in-symfony2)

Comment: I beg to differ: the direction and use case of the other question is completely different.

Comment: Btw.: the down vote is not ok since it's not a duplicate. I checked before posting and couldn't find any duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [pathInfo()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#identifying-a-request) method:

> In your application, you need a way to identify a request; most of the
>   time, this is done via the "path info" of the request, which can be
>   accessed via the `getPathInfo()` method:
>
> ```
> // for a request to http://example.com/blog/index.php/post/hello-world
> // the path info is "/post/hello-world"
> $request->getPathInfo();
> ```

Hope this help

Comment: Excactly what I was looking for, thanx! :-)